# Multiple grids from the same store

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need to display product-wise sales data on grid panels on ExtJs3.2 - one grid per product.
The data is received year-wise,and is loaded into a jsonstore.

```
{"list": [
  {
    "Year": "2014",
    "product": "IS",
    "total": "5.0",
  },
  {
    "Year": "2013",
    "product": "IS",
    "total": "5.6",
  },
  {
    "Year": "2014",
    "product": "NS",
    "total": "5.7",
  },
  {
    "Year": "2013",
    "product": "NS",
    "total": "5.1",
  }
 ....
......
]
```

}

The response is processed to convert into a product-specific 'keyed' dictionary.

```
{ "IS":[{"Year":"2013","total":"5.1"},{"Year":"2013","total":"5.1"}..],
"NS":[{"Year":"2013","total":"5.1"},{"Year":"2013","total":"5.1"}..],
..}
```

Each key(and values) are then loaded into separate array stores to feed the respective grids.

Though simplistic - too many objects/structures are being created to achieve this.
Is there a more elegant way to load multiple grids from  extracts of the store data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have important reasons not to switch to MVC ExtJS 4 or MVVC ExtJS 5 you could provide data the needed way on server side. E.g. by Node.js what is fetching the JSON and reworking this. Your request could be more specific and your client App would become faster.

An other way would be to write convert() functions into your Ext.data fields and use them as source for the grid.